# How to Put image on Navigation bar in Oracle APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

[image]

Can anybody guide me how to proceed..

appreciate your help..

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=11323 user demo/demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to application -> shared component -> Navigation -> Navigation bar List

then  edit navigation bar entries where you will able to see option Image/class.
There you can select Application images /Workspace image ,Once you selected and saved details then image will appear in navigation Bar.
[image]

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Is it still working in 18.2.0.00.12? Because I tried it this way and nothing is shown on the page, except the username.
[image]

Comment: Same thing here. Is it because of the path or something? I'm already using the image in my application, not sure why this is not working.